# Is 雷装 a synonym for 魚雷?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji, etymology, history

During reading of some Japanese Wikipedia articles (e.g. [北上](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E4%B8%8A_(%E8%BB%BD%E5%B7%A1%E6%B4%8B%E8%89%A6)), [重雷装艦](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8D%E9%9B%B7%E8%A3%85%E8%89%A6)) I encountered the compound 雷装｛らいそう｝, which I have been unable to find a definite explanation of.

In their descriptive texts you will find a lot of mentions of 魚雷｛ぎょらい｝. However, it seems that they (北上 and related ships) are a different type of torpedo cruiser, since a torpedo cruiser generally gets called 水雷巡洋艦｛すいらいじゅんようかん｝. The Wikipedia text on 重雷装艦｛じゅうらいそうかん｝ seems to indicate these were remodelled torpedo cruisers into light torpedo cruisers. Did I understand that correctly?

But that still leaves the question open: is 雷装 a synonym for 魚雷, maybe in a similar style how 魚雷 took over from 魚形水雷｛ぎょけいすいらい｝?

Any additional hints or explanations about etymology very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a synonym.

雷装 is short for 魚雷装備 or 雷撃装備, torpedo-attached/rigged/equipped/mounted. According to Wikipedia, Kitakami was originally built as a 軽巡洋艦, light crusing ship (not torpedo cruiser). In August-September 1942, they converted it into 重雷装艦, heavy torpedo-attached ship (removed 3 main guns, rigged with 40 torpedo launcher).

- 地雷 : land mine
- 水雷 : underwater bomb
- 機雷 : short for 機械水雷, machine underwater bomb, naval mine
- 魚雷 : short for 魚形水雷, fish-shaped underwater bomb, torpedo
- 雷撃 : 攻撃 by using 魚雷 , torpedo attack
- 装備 :  equipment, (act of) equipping or equipped
- 装備する :  to equip, to rig, to mount
- 雷装 : short for 魚雷装備 or 雷撃装備, torpedo-equipping or torpedo-equipped
- 爆弾 : bomb
- 爆撃 : aerial bombing
- 爆装 : short for 爆撃装備, aerial-bomb-equipping or aerial-bomb-equipped

Comment: 本当にありがとうございました。It really helps me to put some parts in a proper context.